# Jmockit mock abstract class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, stripes, jmockit

I have a super abstract class

```
public abstract class PsActionBeanContext{
    ...
    abstract public Brand getBrand();
    ..
}
```

I want to mock the abstract class to get default value "TESTUSER_BRAND_ID", which is a constant.
 I tried:

```
final PsActionBeanContext contextFake = new MockUp<PsActionBeanContext>(){
 @Mock
 public Brand getBrand(){
      Brand brand = new Brand();
      brand.setBrandId(TESTUSER_BRAND_ID);
      return brand;
      }
 }.getMockInstance();
}
```

But I got

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to mock abstract method "getBrand"

I tried the same way to mock an interface but that is fine.
 any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Have you tried mockito? It is much easier to use than jmockit.

Comment: I am not the boss, LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
@Test
public void mockAbstractClass(@NonStrict final PsActionBeanContext mock)
{
    final Brand brand = new Brand();
    brand.setBrandId(TESTUSER_BRAND_ID);

    new Expectations() {{ mock.getBrand(); result = brand; }};

    assertSame(brand, mock.getBrand());
}
```